# Changing graphics card: what is this wire for, and how do I unplug it?

Tags: graphics-card, desktop-computer

I am not familiar with computer hardware, and I am trying to change my graphics card. I currently have a *GT 610*, but I am trading it out for a *GTX 1050 Ti* 
**GT on the left, GTX on the right:**
[image: The cards]

**My computer:**
[image]

I am trying to get the GTX to fit, and I am certain it will fit (just barely). The problem is, there are some wires in the way that, if I can move them, I can get the graphics card in, and then easily move the wires around/over/under the card. I was able to move all the other wires, but I am not sure what this one wire is, and I do not want to try to remove it until I do know what it is, and how to remove it.

**The Wire (1):**
[image]

**The Wire (2):**
[image]

What is this wire, and how do I remove it? I would seriously appreciate the help, I just spent $229 dollars on this card, and I don't want it to go to waste.

Comment: The quality of the image is so poor it's impossible to tell what the cable is

Comment: One second, let me edit my post with a better quality image.

Comment: Okay @Ramhound I have a better quality image on it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wire is for a wireless device antenna - Most likely WiFi, but conceivably Bluetooth or even GSM.  It could connect straight to the antenna or - more likely in this case, to another connector to screw in an exteranl antenna.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL

Comment: Thanks! How exactly does the computer use it?

Comment: If you look at the connector, its right next to a chip labelled Atheros AR5B125 - This chip is a WIFI module. It is possible to pop the connector off and reconnect it (I use a small screw driver) - although note it has a limited number of duty cycles.  The computer uses it to connect to WiFi (or can use it to connect to WiFi).

Answer (score 0):

The Wire (1) shows what is either a WiFi or Bluetooth card.

The wire from it will be the antenna for the card. If you use WiFi you will need to have it connected to get a good signal.

You can disconnect it in order to reroute the wire if you need to but you will need to reconnect it if you want to use WiFi on that computer.

Comment: Okay, Is it just as easy as gently pulling it out?